# Free java hosting?

Tags: hosting, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anyone know of any Free Java hosting services?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215870/anyone-know-of-any-free-java-hosting-services)

Could anyone tell me some free hosting on which I can run my java web application even for a day?

I don't want free forever. Free for 2-3 days will be fine

I searched a lot on net but couldn't find anything.

I just have some .html pages and some servlets in my java web application.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)? [GAE has Java servlet support](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html) and is free. Depending on your use of a database is could be pretty easy to get going.tgoo

Answer (score 0):

this might be a duplicate of [another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/215870/anyone-know-of-any-free-java-hosting-services/363891#363891), but here are the comments that I posted for that one....

You could try the Amazon free tier, which gives you a free mini server instance for a year;
http://aws.amazon.com/free/
To get a basic java server select an ubuntu image from the public images and install it on the instance, and then login to the console and run `apt-get install tomcat6 java` to install a java web application container.

There are some more details in this question/answer about using AWS free tier;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216066/how-to-use-amazon-web-service-free-tier

Also Hpcloud.com are offering a beta of their cloud hosting services, which you can sign up for here; http://hpcloud.com/
Which might give you a free instance for a couple of months. (I have been running an instance for about 4 months which is handy for trying out new installs and suchlike and has a much higher RAM limit that the free AWS account)

---

The reason that you might find it difficult to get free java hosting like you might be familiar with for mod_php or cgi scripts is that in general, java applications do not share resources well.
I mean in the sense that for example tomcat has resources allocated per deployed application which means that its not practical to run 100 tomcat wars in the same app server. But the same is not true of php apps running under mod_php where its just the requests running and cached that are consuming RAM. (my very naive understanding...)

Comment: Tom, while there are no issues with providing relevant answers to old questions, copying and pasting a previous answer is just plain laziness. Also these question (recommend me x, any hosting for y) are off-topic for ServerFault (check out the [FaQ]) for more info - although when the questions were posted the FaQ wasn't as clearly as defined as it is now.

Comment: @tombull89 .feel free to delete the answers as off-topic or mark as duplicates, I just noticed a whole series of "why cant I get free shared java hosting?" type questions that had gone un-answered, and given that I had just typed up an answer I didn't see the point of writing novel content for ostensibly the same question.

Comment: @TomH: It's probably best if you flag any more that you find as duplicates of the one you mentioned in your answer - cheers

Comment: @Iain I find the community wiki "feature" that steals your points actually creates an incentive to continue iterations of answers about various things in different question threads so you don't lose the karma.

Comment: @TomH: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/