# Can JSP/ JSF be hosted in shared hosting plans?

Tags: hosting, java, web-hosting, shared-hosting, jsp

I want to use JSF with Facelets/JSP in my website. Can I get Java hosting in shared hosting plans ?

---

*I want to re-develop a business website for my client's company.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some hosting services providing shared tomcat web application hosting, (links removed - but just google "shared tomcat hosting") will get you a reasonable list to work from.

The reason that you might find it difficult to get good quality cheap shared java hosting like you might be familiar with for mod_php or cgi scripts is that in general, java applications do not share resources well.

I mean in the sense that tomcat has resources allocated (such as the classloader and the application classes) per deployed application which means that its not practical to deploy 50  war files in the same app server. But the same is not true of php apps running under mod_php where its just the requests running and cached that are consuming RAM. (my very naive understanding...)

The companies that provide hosting for 20 dollars a month, do so by having maybe 20-100 sites running on each server instance and share the running costs between all customers.

So there is an inherent cost ( memory) associated with running a java application, and it is a pain for smaller businesses as you need to get to the dedicated server level before for cost/performance of Java starts to beat out php apps.

There is no fixed level at which you know when to go up to a dedicated server, it usually happens when your ISP sends you a nasty email telling you to upgrade, or you see "site over page view limits" etc.

If are just looking for somewhere to do some development, you might try some of the beta programmes [mentioned in this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/108088/free-java-hosting/363896#363896)

However after saying all that, I did make a blog post once about shared java hosting, and these were the links that I had previously found with shared war file hosting on tomcat6;

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are asking about shared hosting because you actually want shared hosting or because of the expense typically associated with a VPS. If you are looking for a good, inexpensive VPS, check out Quality Servers. I opened an account with them about a month ago and couldn't be happier. Their prices are dirt cheap and you have full control over your server. I got to them via this link: http://www.lowendbox.com/blog/qualityservers-4-600mb-openvz-vps-in-us-or-uk/, which from what I can tell will get you a cheaper price than shopping from the main page of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is Java Server hosting available. "Cheap" is a relative term, so no comment on that.

If you're asking for recommendations or suggestions, that will be off-topic.